# Python Type Hint werkzeug.test.WrapperTestResponse

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I type hint response in the following code:

```
def test_favicon(client):
    response = client.get("/")
    print("response:", type(response))
```

Output: `response: <class 'werkzeug.test.WrapperTestResponse'>`

I tried importing `from werkzeug.test import WrapperTestResponse` and `response: WrapperTestResponse = client.get("/")`, but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The [werkzeug.test.TestResponse](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/test/#werkzeug.test.TestResponse) class is a subclass of werkzeug.wrappers.Response.

The snippet below shows how to use this:

```py
from werkzeug.wrappers import Response

def test_favicon(client):
    response = client.get("/")

    print(f"Response: {type(response)}")

    assert isinstance(response, Response)
```